# Is there good way to keep kernel module loaded until an associated timer callback returns

Tags: c, timer, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I am writing a kernel module which sets a timer that calls a callback function in the module after some periods.
The code is like the following:

```
static struct timer_list test_timer;
static void timeout_cb(unsigned long data)
{
    printk("cb called\n");
}    
static int __init timer_module_init( void )
{
    init_timer(&test_timer);
    test_timer.expires = jiffies + HZ*5;
    test_timer.data = 0;
    test_timer.function = timeout_cb;
    add_timer(&test_timer);
    return 0;
}
```

I thought that the system will hang up if the module is unloaded before the callback function is called. And, this actually happened.

```
# insmod timer_test.ko && lsmod | grep timer_test && rmmod timer_test.ko
timer_test              1034  0 ### No ref count to the module
### After some seconds, the system hung up
```

I think a simple solution for this problem is incrementing the module's ref count before `add_timer()` and decrementing it at the end of `timeout_cb()`, which keeps the module loaded until `timeout_cb()` ends.

```
static void timeout_cb(unsigned long data)
{
    printk("cb called\n");
    module_put(THIS_MODULE); // decrementing ref count
}    
static int __init timer_module_init( void )
{
...
    try_module_get(THIS_MODULE); // incrementing ref count
    add_timer(&test_timer);
    return 0;
}
```

This seems to work fine, but strictly speaking, the system would hang up if the module is unloaded after `module_put()` returns but before `timeout_cb()` returns.

```
//objdump 
static void timeout_cb(unsigned long data)
{
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  9 <timeout_cb+0x9>
   9:   48 c7 c7 00 00 00 00    mov    $0x0,%rdi
  10:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  12:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  17 <timeout_cb+0x17>
        printk("cb called\n");
        module_put(THIS_MODULE);
  17:   48 c7 c7 00 00 00 00    mov    $0x0,%rdi
  1e:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  23 <timeout_cb+0x23>
}
  // I think the system would hang up if the module is unloaded here.
  23:   c9                      leaveq
  24:   c3                      retq
  25:   90                      nop
```

Is there good way to keep the module loaded until `timeout_cb()` returns completely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `module_exit` function you need to deactivate the timer. You may do that in synchronized way using

```
timer_del_sync(&test_timer);
```

This will garantee that timer's callback isn't executed upon returning. So, only two variants are possible:

1. Timer has been deactivated before callback is executed. Because of deactivation, callback execution will never occures.
2. Timer has been deactivated and callback has been finished.

You may combine this approach with `module_put`/`try_module_get` one, so your callback will be executed in any case.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I will combine your answer with my approach.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution will work fine because `timeout_cb()` is called in interrupt context, although I am not sure this is the regular way.

reference: http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-7-sect-4